# Синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>

#define eof -1;

int main()    
{
  int c;
  printf("Make input>\n");
  c = getchar();
  while (c != eof)  // 1>5.cpp(12): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед ";" куда ")" воткнуть ее, она же там не нужна
  {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf Я уже достиг порога комментариев. Он не приживётся, или практические технари не приживутся, кто знает... Правда это обсуждение уже не по теме ошибки.

Answer (score 4):

Надо определить макрос eof так:

```
#define eof -1
```

Без ; в конце

А еще лучше так:

```
#define eof (-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

В ответе [[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg) (ну и имечко, пальцы сломаешь) дан правильный вариант. Вы в теле макроопределения `eof` ставите `;`. Она же у Вас вставляется в результирующий текст. Что получится, представьте сами. Да и в 21м веке баловаться с определениями констант по `#define` -- не дело. Пользуйтесь хотя бы enum'ами.

Comment: Чем имя не нравится? Нормальное древнескандинавское прозвище :)

Comment: А если по существу, то define очень широко используется для определения констант. Перечисления удобны для определения сразу нескольких констант, а для одной - зачем париться? Хотя, все это дело вкуса. Скорее всего, компилятор выдаст одинаковый ассемблерный код.

Comment: Чем ник не нравится, я уже написал -- пальцы сломать можно. А вот насчёт `#define` -- это макроподстановки, и синтаксический контроль идёт уже позже. Их неосторожное использование ведёт в лучшем случае к непонятным ошибкам, типа вот этой, в худшем -- к ошибкам труднообнаружимым, которые синтаксическим контролем не ловятся. Пришли они с самого начала, когда возможности компьютеров/компиляторов были весьма скромными, и лучше их там и оставить. А для одиночных констант есть описатель `const`

Comment: Да, но у перечислений есть одно ограничение: они позволяют определять только целочисленные константы. Там, где нужны плавающие запятые, текстовые константы и т.д. без макроподстановок не обойдешься. Особенно там, где простые константы могут затормозить работу. Ошибки? С вообще требует большой осторожности. Чего только стоят переполнения буфера или утечки памяти! Я тут в тексте glibc встретил макрос на ~500 строчек текста. Это, конечно, уже перебор. Но ведь работает же! Все приемы хороши на своем месте, у всех свои плюсы и минусы, всем надо пользоваться с умом.

Comment: Излишнее доверие к компилятору ведет к еще более трудноотлавливаемым ошибкам. 

Излишняя строгость языка это страховка для кроликов, не приспособленных для лазания, только мешающая кошкам (умеющим лазать).

Мораль - во всем надо знать меру и тщательно изучать матчасть.

Comment: Про `const` я выше уже добавил. Макрос на 500 строк в glibc работает... Может и работает... `C` -- язык весьма невысокого уровня. А вот определить на глаз вторичное определение символа по `#define` в куче строк (про хедеры и говорить не будем) получается не всегда. И потом можно голову долго ломать: почему в тексте 3, а отладчик говорит 2. Нет уж, нет уж...

Comment: В жизни нужна гибкость...

Comment: Если серьезно, то пока Вам нужен отладчик, "вычислительные" макросы лучше не трогайте.

Comment: "Излишняя строгость языка это страховка для кроликов, не приспособленных для лазания". См. цитату из Х. Карри и Р. Фейса -- эпиграф к предисловию Haskell Language Report. Те, о ком они пишут, считали себя крутыми авторитетами.

Comment: Ссылочку киньте, пожалуйста, а то ведь отслеживать все времени не хватает. Кстати, может я ошибаюсь, но Haskell не очень удачный пример. Это по духу что-то близкое к Prolog , т.е язык утверждений (для избранных, близких к Математике). Думаю в широкой среде практических технарей он не приживется.

Comment: @avp http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf Я уже достиг порога комментариев. Он не приживётся, или практические технари не приживутся, кто знает... Правда это обсуждение уже не по теме ошибки. Автор комментария: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352/alexlz

Answer (score -3):

```
while(c != eof) / 1>5
```

Наверное, все условие должно быть обременно скобками.

Comment: Во-первых, 1>5 - это не условие, а вывод компилятора.

Во-вторых, более вероятно, что проблема в самом eof.